# UWP Multiple Views : The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am getting the error:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

When I create instances of a User Control in a UWP app with multiple views.

When I only have the main view open, the error never happens, so I don't think it's as simple as running UI code in a non-UI thread. I'm ensuring I'm running all UI code through the view's dispatcher, and with only one view, it works perfectly.

However, on creating a new view like this:

```
   CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
                int newViewId = 0;


                await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {


                    var newrootFrame = new Frame();
                    newrootFrame.Navigate(typeof(StarfirePage),null);
                    Window.Current.Content = newrootFrame;

                    newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                    Window.Current.Activate();
                });


                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

Now when I create those User Controls, I get the error. But not every time, I can refresh the list of controls, once, twice, sometimes more,and it's fine, then it'll crash. So basically controls seems to be the correct thread the first few times, and then not.

This problem only happens when I have a second view loaded, otherwise, it never happens, so I'm not thinking this is as simple as create UI components on a non-UI thread, I've been over the code and I'm as sure as I can be that's not happening. It seems there is something odd happening with the new view.

Another odd symptom is that refreshing the controls in the second view slowly tends to work, but if I click the button twice quickly, a crash is guaranteed.

Another strange thing is that if I click to refresh the controls in the first view many times (like 50 times, clicked really fast), then open up the second view, the crash will happen right away, almost like the events for the first view have ended up on the second view, and of course, the wrong dispatcher is being used.

Any input on this really appreciated.

Cheers

Garry

Comment: On which thread does this code run? [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_) is meant to schedule a callback to run on the UI thread **from a worker thread**. At any rate, properly formatting code goes a long way.

Comment: Can you share callstack, crashdump and/or repro sample for the crash? Does your app use any 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. My controls were using FontAwesome.UWP components (the library is on Nuget) and that has a problem with multiple views as it uses a static FontFamily which is being used by multiple dispatcher threads. I changed the FontAwesome library to use a FontFamily instance for each dispatcher, and now it works great. I will suggest the fix to the maintainer of the library.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. Do you want to post this as answer to your question? This way we'll get the question off the unanswered list. Thanks!